# Serialize a M-2-M relation with grouping in Django REST framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models, linked through a separate model as follow:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    project = models.ManyToManyField(
        Project,
        through='Schedule'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Schedule(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)
    hours = models.IntegerField()
```

Serialized is pretty straight forward:

```py
class EmployeeScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    month = serializers.DateField()
    booked = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'month', 'booked']
```

A viewset returns the total number of houses assigned to each employee for different projects, summed over dates:

```py
class ScheduleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeScheduleSerializer

    lookup_field = 'employee'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Employee.objects.values(
            'name', month=F('schedule__date')
        ).annotate(
            booked=Sum('schedule__hours', distinct=True)
        )

        if self.request.query_params.get('id') is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(id=self.request.query_params.get('id'))
        return qs

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

In the output we have multiple records for each employee:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "month": "10/01/2020",
        "booked": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "month": "11/01/2020",
        "booked": 120
    },
...
]
```

I want to convert it to a nested list so that the booked hours show up as a list for each employee. I checked multiple threads, but couldn't find a reasonable solution. I think it's possible to convert it to a grouped dataframe and output as JSON, but it wouldn't be part of the Django Rest framework.

As far as I know, Django ORM doesn't support nested queryset. Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a EmployeeSerializer with a nested serializer with Schedule.

First, to improve reading, you should add a related name to schedule

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="booked_hours")
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)
    hours = models.IntegerField()
```

To have the booked hours, you can update the model :

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    project = models.ManyToManyField(
        Project,
        through='Schedule'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def booked_hours_count:
        return [ dict(date=date, count=self.booked_hours.filter(date=date).count()) for date in set(self.booked_hours.values_list('date', flat=True))]
```

and then in the serializer

```
class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ['id', 'project', 'date', 'hours']

class EmployeeScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    booked_hours = ScheduleSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'booked_hours', 'booked_hours_count']
```

Thanks to that, you will have :

```
[
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "booked_hours": [
            {
               "project":...,
               "hours"....,
               "date"...
            },
        ],
...
]
```

To optimize the queryset, you should not forget to use `prefect_related`.
The viewset will be :

```
class ScheduleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeScheduleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Employee.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('booked_hours')
        return queryset
```

`ReadOnlyModelViewSet`is doing the rest of the job here.

Comment: Thanks! I just can't get it working on my side. Are you using the `qs = Employee.objects.values(
            'name', month=F('schedule__date')
        ).annotate(
            booked=Sum('schedule__hours', distinct=True)
        )` I mentioned in my question?

Comment: No you are right. It is obsolete with these serializers. I update my answer

Comment: I actually need to get sum over all projects by each date and use that value as the booked hours. This is the hard part to get it working!

Comment: In output I need to have hours and date for each employee, project should be omitted in annotation phase.

Comment: All right, I made a modif : you can use a property. For the project, you just need to remove the string from the serializer.

Comment: Oh I realize you want booked_hours by date. I will make another proposition ;)

Comment: Appreciate your help! The only problem left is that we can have multiple projects per employee with different hours. So to get the booked hours, I need to group schedule for each employee by date and then sum them. Is it possible to add this final step to the property you defined for Employee model?

Comment: Yes, it is possible ;) I will add that tomorrow morning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224021/discussion-between-henri-and-mehdi-zare).